# Implement Multi-threading on Java Program

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a little Java program which uses `PsExec.exe` from cmd launched using `ProcessBuilder` to copy and install an application on networked PC (the number of PC that will need to be installed can vary from 5 to 50).

The program works fine if I launched `ProcessBuilder` for each PC sequentially.

However to speed things up I would like to implement some form of **MultiThreading** which could allow me to install 5 PC's at the time concurrently (one "batch" of 5 X `Processbuilder` processes untill all PC's have been installed).

I was thinking of using a Fixed Thread Pool in combination with a Callable interface (each execution of `PsExec` returns a value which **indicates** if the execution was **succesfull** and which I have to **evaluate**).

The code used for the `ProcessBuilder` is:

```
            // Start iterating over all PC in the list:
            for(String pc : pcList)
            {
                counter++;

                logger.info("Starting the installation of remote pc: " + pc); 
                updateMessage("Starting the installation of remote pc: " + pc); 


                int exitVal = 99;                    
                logger.debug("Exit Value set to 99");

                try 
                {                        
                    ProcessBuilder pB = new ProcessBuilder();
                    pB.command("cmd", "/c", 
                            "\""+psExecPath+"\"" + " \\\\" + pc + userName + userPassword + " -c" + " -f" + " -h" + " -n 60 " + 
                                    "\""+forumViewerPath+"\"" + " -q "+ forumAddress + remotePath + "-overwrite");                        

                    logger.debug(pB.command().toString()); 

                    pB.redirectError();
                    Process p = pB.start();
                    InputStream stErr = p.getErrorStream();
                    InputStreamReader esr = new InputStreamReader(stErr);
                    BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader(esr);

                    String line = null;

                    line = bre.readLine();

                    while (line != null)
                    {
                        if(!line.equals(""))
                            logger.info(line);                
                        line = bre.readLine();
                    }
                    exitVal = p.waitFor();
                } catch (IOException ex) 
                {
                    logger.info("Exception occurred during installation of PC: \n"+pc+"\n "+ ex);
                    notInstalledPc.add(pc);
                }

                if(exitVal != 0)
                {
                    notInstalledPc.add(pc);
                    ret = exitVal;
                    updateMessage("");                    
                    updateMessage("The remote pc: " + pc + " was not installed"); 
                    logger.info("The remote pc: " + pc + " was not installed. The error message returned was: \n"+getError(exitVal) + "\nProcess exit code was: " + exitVal);
                }
                else
                {
                    updateMessage("");                    
                    updateMessage("The remote pc: " + pc + " was succesfully installed");                          
                    logger.info("The remote pc: " + pc + " was succesfully installed");                                                  
                }
```

Now I've read some info on how to implement Callable and I would like to enclose my `ProcessBuilder` in a Callable interface and then **submit** all the Tasks for running in the for loop.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surely do that. I suppose you want to use Callable instead of runnable to get the result of your `exitVal` ?

It doesn't seem like you have any shared data between your threads, so I think you should be fine. Since you even know how many Callables you are going to make you could create a collection of your Callables and then do

```
List<Future<SomeType>> results = pool.invokeAll(collection)
```

This would allow for easier handling of your result. Probably the most important thing you need to figure out when deciding on whether or not to use a threadpool is what to do if your program terminates while threads are still running; Do you HAVE to finish what you're doing in the threads, do you need to have seamless handling of errors etc.

Check out java threadpools doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html
or search the web, there are tons of posts/blogs about when or not to use threadpools.

But seems like you're on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply! It definitely put me on the right track. I ended up implementing it like this:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5); //NEW                                

            List<Future<List<String>>> resultList = new ArrayList<>(); 

            updateMessage("Starting the installation of all remote pc entered..."); 

            // Start iterating over all PC in the list: 
            for(String pc : pcList)
            {
                counter++;

                logger.debug("Starting the installation of remote pc: " + pc); 

                psExe p = new psExe(pc);
                Future<List<String>> result = executor.submit(p);//NEW
                resultList.add(result);
            }

            for(Future<List<String>> future : resultList)
            {.......
```

in the last for loop I read the result of my operations and write them on screen or act according to the result returned.

I still have a couple of questions as it is not really clear to me:

1 - If I have 20 PC and submit all the callable threads to the pool in my first For loop, do I get it correctly that only 5 threads will be started (threadpool size = 5) but all will already be created and put in Wait status, and only as soon as the first running Thread is complete and returns a result value the next one will automatically start until all PC are finished?

2 - What is the difference (advantage) of using invokeall() as you suggested compared to the method I used (submit() inside the for loop)?

Thank you once more for your help...I really Love this Java stuff!! ;-)

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I had in mind, good job! As for your questions:
1: when you create a fixedthreadpool of size 5, 5 threads will be started whether you have <5, 5 or >5 tasks sbumitted to the pool. If there are more than 5 they simply wait as you say.
2: invokeAll was simply a suggestion to have more control. Unlike submit, invokeAll blocks until all your tasks have completed. This was because you seemed to have so few tasks, but if you have more, you should probably consider using submit or a timeconstrained variant of invokeAll instead so as to handle results on the fly.

Comment: Hy I have another question, if I would like to get one result as soon as each Thread is finished without waiting for all Threads in the Pool to complete how is the best way to achieve this? Can I tell each Thread to notify me the result as soon as finished? Thank you